# gae search service data storage

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, google-cloud-datastore

In order to use the new GAE search service, data must be created using the Document object (built with the Document.Builder class). Does anyone have a feel for how document style CRUD will compare with using JDO or JPA for the same data? Specifically performance, for example, create data, update data, etc... If they are comparable, why not always use document style data storage?